# Android: ActionBarSherlock Title Ellipsize

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, title

Is there a way to prevent the title of the ActionBar (sherlock) from getting cropped (like ThisIsMyTi...)

I'd like to always see the title in full length, so the title should always have the highest priority except the overflow menu button on devices without a hardware menu button.

Would be nice if there was a solution. Setting the ellipsize of the title to null doesn't work, it just gets cropped without the ...

Answer (score 0):

Add on the top:

```
private TextView titleTV;
```

In your OnCreate:

```
ActionBar Bar=getSupportActionBar();
Bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bar, null);
titleTV = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.title);
titleTV.setSelected(true);
Bar.setCustomView(customView);
Bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

And in bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:singleLine="true"           
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:text="">
    <requestFocus
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can set title with

```
titleTV.setText(t);
```